# What does desktop_Icon mean?

Tags: application-development

I've submitted an app to the software store but it gets sent back with this error:-

```
desktop_Icon
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the .desktop file entry, there’s the line which starts with “Icon=”. This part is especially important as it will show the icon of your app, which will distinguish it from other entries.

When providing the icon file name, make sure you:

- Use no absolute paths (ie. /usr/share/icons/…)
- Use an icon which you actually ship in your app
- Specify the 'Icon=' key in the .desktop file
- Put the icon in the root of your project (i.e. Icon=./icon.png)

Comment: So in which folder should I save this said icon?

Comment: Just put the icon in the root directory of your project.