# How to package QML Extension Library + Tabbed Touch UI?

Tags: application-development

I have followed the method described [here] (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/1215913) for creating QML Extension Library + Tabbed Touch UI project and generate click package. But the generated click package doesn't approved in Ubuntu Software Store for following reasons

"desktop_Exec (dudeescape)": {
"link": "[What does desktop_Exec mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417381/what-does-desktop-exec-mean/417382)",
"text": "absolute path '/usr/bin/qmlscene -I backend/modules app/dudeescape.qml' for Exec given in .desktop file."
},
"desktop_Icon (dudeescape)": {
"link": "[What does desktop_Icon mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417369/what-does-desktop-icon-mean/417370)",
"text": "'@ICON@' specified as icon in .desktop file for app 'dudeescape', which is not available in the click package."
}